# using OAuth in Application backed by App Engine

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I have been exploring several options and I was hoping someone could elaborate on the best way to accomplish this:

I am making a mobile application backed by app engine. the app engine portion uses google apis and I need to verify the user fromt he application then send that to the backend. Should I pass a OAuth token or is there another way to accomplish this? Also, the application will have a bunch of different packages, should I hold onto the token from the app and continually pass it in or pass it once and hang onto it in the backend?

Any expertise or links would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
- Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should follow the official guide on google. In your case, you should look at

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Answer (score 1):

See the following guide regarding "Cross Client Authentication":
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

Specifically the section on "Android app obtains offline access for Web back-end" which I believe speaks to this scenario.